# CurrentPageReference in Debug Flow context

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, pagereference

It seems that a Wire call to CurrentPageReference does not work when the LWC is embedded in a Flow Screen when run in the context of Flow Debug mode. This works when the LWC is embedded in a page, and when the Flow is run for real.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? What else does the Flow Debug mode not do?

```
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    receivePageReference(data) {
        console.log('receivePageReference data: ' + data);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess - in the context of debug the current page reference cannot be fulfilled since the flow isn't actually running in a Salesforce UI page. I'd then hypothesize that the value returned from lightning/navigation is undefined or null. Which in turn means the wire cannot be evaluated, and the wire function is not invoked. As to what else won't be initialized fully in flow debugging, that's an interesting question that I cannot answer.